# Azure AD Authentication Error: User Cancelled the flow

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to develop user authentication functionality of our application using `Azure AD` and having some issue in the process. I have implemented the `client-flow` authentication using `ADAL` library but when I try to login it is giving an error as below:

```
Error: User cancelled the flow RequestId:934620772 CorrelationId: 57a1ffe8-7612-49c4-b22d-2704eff74010
at fail (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-ms-adal/www/CordovaBridge.js:37:25)
at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:295:52)
at <anonymous>:1:9(anonymous function) @ main.js:121821_rejected @ utility.js:286Deferred.reject @ utility.js:368(anonymous function) @ AuthenticationContext.js:91_rejected @ utility.js:286Deferred.reject @ utility.js:368fail @ CordovaBridge.js:41cordova.callbackFromNative @ cordova.js:295(anonymous function) @ VM298:1
```

We are developing this app using Ionic 2 framework which uses Angular 2 and TypeScript. And I am using `cordova-plugin-ms-adal` library for my development.

Would appreciate if you could please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the "**resourceUri**" value I was using in order to connect with Azure AD using **ADAL** library (cordova-plugin-ms-adal).

I was using my **Azure App Service's URI** but what it really needs is the **Graph API URI (https://graph.windows.net)**.

Comment: This solved my problem too, although I am on Android.

Answer (score 0):

````
  at Br.s [as constructor] (msal-browser.min.js:2:4145)
  at new Br (msal-browser.min.js:2:67586)
  at Br.createUserCancelledError (msal-browser.min.js:2:66371)
  at msal-browser.min.js:2:86314
(anonymous) @ HomePage.jsx:70
HomePage.jsx:72 User cancelled the authentication flow.```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).