# MS ADAL Integration : Authentication failed Error: User cancelled the flow RequestId on Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic4, adal

I am try to integrate [Ms ADAL](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ms-adal/) on ionic 4 but i am getting

> Authentication failed Error: User cancelled the flow RequestId

My code :

```
import { MSAdal, AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationResult } from '@ionic-native/ms-adal/ngx';

constructor(
private msAdal: MSAdal
  ) {}

  let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');
      authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', 'MY-ID-CLIENT', 'http://localhost:8000/','','')
      .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
        console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
        console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
      })
      .catch((e: any) => console.log('Authentication failed', e));
```

[image: error screenshot]

Any help pls ? Thanks !

Comment: Have you see this similar [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/issues/179)

Comment: thanks for your help ! I  i change the value of resourceURL into `"https://graph.windows.net/"` and it not works for me. nothing has changed.

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity pls what does this error mean and  what is the cause? thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: As per your code the issue is happening while acquiring the token, it may be with the resourceUri/clientId. Reference [Link1](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/issues/179#issuecomment-457677817) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851228/azure-ad-authentication-error-user-cancelled-the-flow)

Comment: thank you  @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I add https://graph.windows.net/ and rebuid app and now it works well !!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

After adding graph.windows.net and rebuid app will resolve the issue.

Please find the references [Link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/issues/179#issuecomment-457677817) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851228/azure-ad-authentication-error-user-cancelled-the-flow)